# how to regex match with the special character /?

Tags: javascript, regex, match

I'm trying to build a regex to determine if a string contains `/i/` (no regex yet)
This is complicated because the symbol `/` is already used in regex

I'm going at it like:

```
console.log('string/i/'.match(/i/))
```

Comment: To escape those reserved characters use \ in front of them.

Comment: Also why use regex when there's nothing dynamic in what you're searching for?

Comment: what better way is there to detect those characters in a string ?

Comment: @coiso It may be overkill to use a regular expression if you are not looking for a *pattern* but an actual string literal itself.

Comment: something like str.indexOf("wtv") is lighter ?

Comment: @coiso Yes, if that's what you are indeed searching for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you aren't doing much "pattern matching" here, it's probably more intuitive to simply not use regular expressions in the first place, so you never have to worry about which characters do or don't need escaping:

```
console.log('string/i/'.indexOf('/i/') !== -1);
```

But if you must use regexp, simply escape the slashes with backslashes:

```
console.log(!!'string/i/'.match('\/i\/'));
```

Pretty much all of this is in the comments, but for some reason no one had made an answer out of it yet.